# Slicer doesn't show column with zero value

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple table:

```
Date                   Sex  Value
Sunday 1 January 2023   M   11
Sunday, 1 January 2023  F   25
Țuesday 10 January 2023 M   45
Țuesday 10 January 2023 F   5
Friday, 20 January 2023 M   10
```

A matrix with a slicer shows:

And on the 20 January it shows only male:

But i like to see it with "F" column with 0 values. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following:

1. Create a new Table for the Sex dimension - like

| Sex |
| --- |
| F |
| M |

2. Add a relationship from this new table (Dim Sex) to your data table
3. Create a new Measure:

```
Total = COALESCE(SUM('your table'[Value]), 0)
```

4. Update your matrix to use the `'Dim Sex'[Sex]` for the Columns, and the new `Total` measure for the matrix value.

Comment: Thanks @SamNseir. How can I write YTD measure "Value YTD = TOTALYTD(SUM('Sheet1'[Value]), 'Sheet1'[Date].[Date], 'Sheet1'[Date]<=SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Date]))" with COALESCE function.

Comment: ```Value YTD = COALESCE( TOTALYTD(SUM('Sheet1'[Value]), 'Sheet1'[Date].[Date], 'Sheet1'[Date]<=SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Date])), 0)
```
Or for readability:
`Value YTD = 
  VAR x = TOTALYTD(SUM('Sheet1'[Value]), 'Sheet1'[Date].[Date], 'Sheet1'[Date]<=SELECTEDVALUE(Sheet1[Date]))
  RETURN COALESCE(x, 0)
`

Comment: All those gives YTD value 0 for F when I select 20 Jan on slicer. But it should be value 30.

Comment: I believe I have answered your original question. Please post a new question as this has moved on from the original. Before doing so, I suggest your do some research on Date tables and YTD calculations. Ultimately, you will need a date table. If I have answered your original question, then please accept, so that others can benefit.